# Create an event to recognise when text on a page changes?

Tags: jquery

There's a page that I'm trying to trigger a jQuery event for when a certain span's value changes to 1.

There's a countdown timer on the page. When the timer reaches 1, I'd like to trigger a click event.

The difficulty I'm having is getting a script that i'm running via Jash to know when the timer changes to 1.

The value of the timer can read with: `$('#tCounter_474754 .bid_time_highlight').text();`

But how can I get jQuery to trigger the click when this timer reaches 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first by setting a `setInterval` check the text of span periodically

and the second solution is to change an attribute of element like class name and set a handler earlier to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just set a timer for the event when the countdown starts? For instance, if the countdown starts from 150s you would trigger the event 149s after you start it.